# symfony - admin 404

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm trying to create a custom 404 page in my admin when something goes wrong and a 404 is thrown.

In my settings.yml file in:

> apps/admin/config/settings.yml

I have the following:

```
all:
   .actions:
    # 404 module/action
    error_404_module:       common
    error_404_action:       error404
```

I have the module 'common' in my modules folder and I've defined an action called:

> executeError404()

and also the template:

> error404Success.php

But for some reason, this action never seems to get called as I've tried an  exit(); but it still calls the default 404 error message that symfony throws.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom 404 page doesn't show when in dev mode. If you change your front controller to the production one you should see it if it's configured correctly.

So rather than going to `frontend_dev.php` got to `frontend.php` or `index.php` depending on your setup.

Comment: even If I change my admin_dev.php front controller to: ('admin', 'prod', true); and go to apage that doesn't exist, I still get the errors that symfony generates and not my page...

Comment: try changing your function definition to take the request object `public function executePage404(sfWebRequest $request)` also, make sure to clear your cache `./symfony cc`

Comment: that didn't seem to work. I'm still getting the same symfony default 404 error message

Comment: are you aware, that this 404 page will only be rendered when you call `forward404` or similar function within an action on that admin module? If you're hoping you can just type in a random url and symfony will know to load this 404 page that's not how it works.

Comment: you could try moving you settings.yml into your root config folder though. All app level configs can me moved into your root config folder to be system wide rather than app wide since the yml config files cascade.